# How to change the button color which consists of divs on press and back?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, onclick

I have a react component which must be a custom button and contains from 2 divs and 1 . My goal here is to implement a function that changes the color from white to orange after onclick and becomes white again after I click somewhere else on the screen.

This is my first react project and I tried multiple approaches already and it still doesn´t work even if the code compiles.. Any suggestions here guys?

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';



export default function PointMark() {
    
    return (
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.touchPoint}>
            <div style={styles.outerCircle}>
                <div style={styles.innerCircle}></div>
            </div>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }

// Styles
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    touchPoint: {
        width: 68,
        height: 68,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        borderRadius: 50,
        border: "3px solid #ffffff",
    },
    outerCircle: {
        width: 42,
        height: 42,
        borderRadius: 50,
        border: "3px solid #ffffff",
        position: 'relative',
    },
    innerCircle: {
        width: 22,
        height: 22,
        borderRadius: 50,
        backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
        position: 'absolute',
        top: 10,
        left: 10,
    }
  });
```

Comment: Create a state (using `useState`) that will be holding the name of the class of the "button" and try adding an `onClick` on the "button" that will change the value of this state.

Answer (score 0):

How about using something like [react-native-webhooks](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-web-hooks)?

For your case, perhaps this:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { useActive } from 'react-native-web-hooks';

export default function PointMark() {
    const ref = React.useRef(null);
    const isActive = useActive(ref);
    return (
        <TouchableOpacity
            ref={ref}
            style={{
                ...styles.touchPoint,
                ...(isActive && styles.touchPointActive)
            }}>
            <div style={styles.outerCircle}>
                <div
                    style={{
                        ...styles.innerCircle
                        ...(isActive && styles.innerCircleActive)
                    }}
                />
            </div>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }

// Styles
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    touchPoint: {
        width: 68,
        height: 68,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        borderRadius: 50,
        border: "3px solid #ffffff",
    },
    touchPointActive: {
        border: "3px solid #ff8000",
    },
    outerCircle: {
        width: 42,
        height: 42,
        borderRadius: 50,
        border: 'inherit',
        position: 'relative',
    },
    innerCircle: {
        width: 22,
        height: 22,
        borderRadius: 50,
        backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
        position: 'absolute',
        top: 10,
        left: 10,
    },
    innerCirlceActive: {
        backgroundColor: '#ff8000',
    }
});
```

A few things to note:

1. I set the `border` property on the `outerCircle` to inherit, that way you don't need to define the `border` again
2. `div` elements that are empty may be self-closing e.g. `<div />`

Here's the example they use on [their NPM page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-web-hooks):

```js
import { useRef } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Linking, Text, Platform } from 'react-native';

import { useHover, useFocus, useActive } from 'react-native-web-hooks';

function Link({ children, href = '#' }) {
    const ref = useRef(null);
    const isHovered = useHover(ref);
    const isFocused = useFocus(ref);
    const isActive = useActive(ref);

    return (
        <Text
            accessibilityRole="link"
            href={href}
            draggable={false}
            onPress={() => Linking.openURL(href)}
            tabIndex={0}
            ref={ref}
            style={[
                styles.text,
                isHovered && styles.hover,
                isFocused && styles.focused,
                isActive && styles.active,
            ]}>
        {children}
    </Text>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    text: {
        ...Platform.select({
            web: {
                cursor: 'pointer',
                outlineStyle: 'none',
                borderBottomWidth: 1,
                borderBottomColor: 'transparent',
                transitionDuration: '200ms',
            },
            default: {},
        }),
    },
    active: {
        color: 'blue',
        borderBottomColor: 'blue',
        opacity: 1.0,
    },
    hover: {
        opacity: 0.6,
    },
    focused: {
        borderBottomColor: 'black',
    },
});
```